# Find all questions on the Stack Exchange network that have been closed

Tags: support, search, closed-questions

Is it possible to view, at a glance, all questions on the Stack Exchange network that have been closed?

I want to help recategorize questions that were posted on the wrong site, so that they can be migrated and re-opened on the correct Stack Exchange site.

Comment: for searching closed Qs you can use `closed:1`, but that won't help in this case since from all possible closing reasons, you only want the _off topic_ one (I assume), also you want from all sites rather than a specific one. Maybe the [DataExplorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) can help

Answer (score 1):

I have created the following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/534090/find-all-questions-on-the-stackexchange-network-that-have-been-closed) for you that shows all closed questions across all sites in the network. As you can imagine this is quite a list and currently SEDE shows a maximum of 50,000 questions.

```sql
-- Result table, don't rename and keep the site column
create table #results ( site nvarchar(250)
                       , postid int
                       , title nvarchar(250)
                       , closeddate datetime
                       , closereason nvarchar(200)
                       );

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''   -- Holds build up SQL string

-- Build one biq union SQL, for each database
select @sql = @sql
+ iif( len(@sql) > 1
     , 'union'
     , 'insert into #results'
) +
-- Here goes the per-site query, fully qualify the database objects
N'
select ''' + name + '''
     ,  p.id
     , p.title
     , p.closeddate
     , ct.name
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posthistory ph
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posts p on p.id = ph.postid
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.closereasontypes ct on ct.id = cast(comment as tinyint)
where posthistorytypeid = 10 -- close
and p.closeddate is not null
'
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
-- and (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')

--print @sql

-- Execute it
exec (@sql)

-- Show results
select site ,
       -- URL builder from Lamak http://stackoverflow.com/a/38129701
      'http://'
      + case PARSENAME(site,1)
        when 'audio' then 'avp'
        else PARSENAME(site,1)
        end
      + coalesce('.'
        + case PARSENAME(site,2)
          when 'audio' then 'avp'
          else PARSENAME(site,2)
          end , '')
      + IIF(patindex('%.MathOverflow%',site) > 0
      , ''
      , coalesce('.' + PARSENAME(site,3), '')
      )
      + IIF(patindex('%.MathOverflow%',site) > 0
      , '.net'
      , '.com'
      )
      + '/q/'
      + cast(postid as nvarchar)
      + '|'
      + title
      -- The rest of the columns
      , closeddate
      , closereason
from #results
order by closeddate desc

drop table #results
```

When run today, the result looks like this:

[image: List of all closed questions, network wide]

Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated once a week, in the weekend.